# getting the unique values rowise?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, row

I have a `column` with different activities separated by `,`

```
Activities

Bathing the puppy, cooking for family
cooking for family, cooking for family
morning walk, cooking for family, Bathing the puppy
Bathing the puppy, Bathing the puppy,Bathing the puppy
```

How can I make a separate `column` with count of distinct activities of each row.

I would like the output to be as follows:

```
Activities                                                  Unique Activities

Bathing the puppy, cooking for family                         2
cooking for family, cooking for family                        1
morning walk, cooking for family, Bathing the puppy           3
Bathing the puppy, Bathing the puppy,Bathing the puppy        1
```

I tried `nunique` method in `pandas` but this work on whole column rather than giving me distinct values in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a real example, you may need to deal with capitalization and punctuation issues. Specify `axis=1` in `nunique` so it operates across the rows.

```
df['Unique Activities'] = df.Activities.str.split(r',\s?', expand=True).nunique(1)
```

Output:

```
                                               Activities  Unique Activities
0                   Bathing the puppy, cooking for family                  2
1                  cooking for family, cooking for family                  1
2     morning walk, cooking for family, Bathing the puppy                  3
3  Bathing the puppy, Bathing the puppy,Bathing the puppy                  1
```

Comment: The solution works .Thanks a lot for the quick reply and saving my day :)

Comment: Just a query, what exactly  `(r',\s?', expand=True)` is doing ? @ALollz

Comment: @suryarahul it is splitting the strings based on a comma and an optional space, which is needed in the last row. So the separators are `','` or `', '`. The expand turns into a `DataFrame` so we can use `nunique()` across the split strings. If you look at `df.Activities.str.split(r',\s?', expand=True)` you can see what it split your string into.

Comment: Thanks a lot for rectifying my doubt :)